# Getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to fetch text field value to my controller and do the search with database but i got the following error.

Error:

```
NoMethodError in HomesController#scan_hcsy

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Site/swargadwar

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:38:in `scan_hcsy'
```

Please check my below code and try to resolve this error.

## homes/hcsy_html.erb

```
<% if current_admin %>
<div class="header">
<div class="navbar-header">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality,govt of odisha</div>
<div class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
<div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div class="name-div">

</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-div">
<div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/homes/registration">Create User</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/hcsy">Scan Report</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">View and Payment Report</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/homes/hcsy">HCSY</a></li>

   </ul>
  </li>

   <li><a href="#">Payment Validate</a></li>
   <li><a href="/sessions/removeadmin">Log Out</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="content-div">
    Logged in as:<%= current_admin.email %>
    <center><h1>HARICHANDRA SAHAYATA YOJANA SLIP</h1></center>
    <%= form_for :hcsy,:url => {:action =>'scan_hcsy' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :reciept,placeholder:"Get your scan code" %>
    <%= f.submit "search" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def registration
        @user=User.new
    end
    def usersave
        @admin=Admin.find(params[:id])
        @user=User.new(params[:user])
        @user.admin_id=@admin.id
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index"
        else
            flash[:alert]="User could not created"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'registration'
        end
    end
    def hcsy_reg
        @hcsy=THcsy.new
    end
    def create_reg
        @hcsy=THcsy.new(params[:hcsy])
        if @hcsy.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'hcsy_reg'
        end
    end
    def scan_hcsy
        @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:hcsy][:receipt])
        if @hcsy
            flash[:notice]="Check the record"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'scanrecord'
        else
            flash[:alert]="Receipt number could not found"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'hcsy'
        end
    end
    def hcsy
        @hcsy=THcsy.new
    end
    def scan_record

    end
end
```

## model/t_hcsy.rb

```
class THcsy < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Address, :Amount_Required, :B_Audio, :B_Thumb, :B_photo, :Beneficiary_Name, :Beneficiary_Rel_With_Decease, :Brahmin, :Business, :Created_by, :D_photo, :Date_Of_Required, :Deceased_Name, :Govt_Service, :HCSY_ID, :Land_Property, :Mobile_No, :Occupation, :Others, :PoliceStation, :Prev_Amount_Received, :Prev_Date_Recieved, :Prev_Receipt_No, :Receipt_No, :Recieved_Fund_Earlier, :Sdp_Id, :Updated_By,:BPL
  attr_accessor :receipt
end
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this might be related, but in your template you have `<%= f.text_field :reciept,placeholder:"Get your scan code" %>` - `:reciept`, but in controller you are trying to access `params[:hcsy][:receipt]` - `:receipt`. It looks like a typo in template - could you correct it and test if it works?

Comment: Can you post your `params` that are coming in the request?

Comment: Now it started to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your params.

Try adding some debugging code, such as:

```
  def scan_hcsy
+   raise ArgumentError if params.nil? 
+   raise ArgumentError if params[:hcsy].nil?
+   raise ArgumentError if params[:hcsy][:receipt].nil?
```

Try fixing this spelling:

```
- <%= f.text_field :reciept, ...
+ <%= f.text_field :receipt, ...
```

Comment: Thanks joelparkerhenderson for this help i did it.Can you tell me if  I will remove search button and when i the textfield will have the desired value how can i excute that action(i.e-scan_hcsy) inside controller.

Comment: Can you write more about what exactly you want? (I don't understand your comment question; for example, are you asking about something like an AJAX automatic submit?)

Comment: Hi joelparkerhenderson,lets take a example suppose i scanned one barcode ,its value will suddenly display in text field,as soon as the text field will get the value that action should excute inside controller,This is what i need.

Comment: One way to solve your need is to use JavaScript and an "onChange" event. When the value in the field changes, the browser runs the JavaScript, and that sends the field's value to the Rails app. Read about Rails and AJAX, and form helpers, and optionally jQuery.